# ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor auto-render mode use different design templates with multiple areas

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

Can areas containing different design templates be created in a project created with ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor auto render mode (server and webassembly)?

For example:

- There must be an administrative template on the Blazor Server side and MudBlazor must be used.
- There must be a portfolio template on the Blazor Webassembly side and Bootstrap must be used.

I've been looking at this new project template that comes with .NET 8 for a while. Is it correct to use this sample project model that I am trying to explain with the new template?

In projects developed in .NET 7 and earlier versions with Blazor WebAssembly app ASP.NET Core hosted, the management side was also located in Blazor WebAssembly. In the new project template that comes with .NET 8, both Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly can be used together.

Therefore, I thought it might be safer to run the management side on the Blazor Server side. However, in this new template, I could not accommodate two different design templates separately. In .NET 7 and earlier, Blazor WebAssembly `index.html` was in the `wwwroot` folder. In the new template, `index.html` is used in `App.razor` on the Blazor Server side and is common for both Server and WebAssembly.